# Does R (real number line) have linear order?

Tags: general-topology

I'm not sure if R has linear order, I know that it has the property of transitivity and comparability but I'm not sure if it has Nonreflexivity.

Comment: I presume you're asking whether "$<$" is a linear order on $\mathbb{R}$. Can we ever have $x<x$?

Comment: no I am not asking for order relations. I have a problem that ask: prove that P(P(R)) is not cardinality aleph-one or aleph-two and that P(P(R)) has a subject of cardinality aleph-three. does my question make sense with respect to my problem?

Comment: That has nothing to do with the question you've asked - what does a set being ordered or not have to do with its cardinality?

Answer (score 1):

$(\mathbb{R}, <)$ is non-reflexive and $(\mathbb{R}, \le)$ is reflexive.   When people say something like "$\mathbb{R}$ has a linear order", they're leaving it up to you whether to use a reflexive or non-reflexive relation symbol.    You can do either one, or both, just so long as you don't get confused which is which.